# Como inserir sons em um aplicativo híbrido?

Tags: app-hibrido

Boa noite, sou iniciante em programação e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo híbrido. Preciso reproduzir um som específico ao tocar em uma imagem da tela... estou utilizando o bootstrap para fazer o layout da aplicação. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, sim, é possível utilizando a tag audio do HTML.
Voce precisa especificar uma url, ou o caminho do arquivo que irá reproduzir. É possível ocultar o player utilizando display: none.
Quanto a reprodução, pode-se usar uma função Javascript na sua tag img, onde, ao clicar na imagem, é disparado uma trigger (gatilho) para reproduzir o audio.
Segue o exemplo da tag audio:

```
 <audio src="caminho_do_arquivo.mp3" style="display: none;" id="id_audio"> 
 </audio>
```

Juntamente com a função js:

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="caminho_da_imagem.png" 
  onclick="$('#id_audio').trigger('play');">
```